# Geodesic deviation equation in flat spacetime $\sim$ divergence of geodesics

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, geodesics

[image: Geodesic]

Consider the above two neighbouring geodesics $\mathcal{Y}$ given by $x^{\alpha}(\sigma)$ and $\mathcal{\tilde{Y}}$ by $\tilde{x}^{\alpha}(\sigma)$ for top and bottom curves respectively. Vector connecting two geodesics is $\xi^{\alpha}(\sigma)$. After going through some calculations, geodesic deviation equation takes the form of

$$\frac{D^2 \xi^{\alpha}}{D \sigma^2} + R^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu \lambda}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d \sigma}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d \sigma}\xi^{\nu} = 0$$

In flat spacetime where Riemann tensor vanishes, one gets

$$\frac{d^2 \xi^{\alpha}}{d \sigma^2}= 0$$

which gives $\xi^{\alpha}(\sigma) = A^{\alpha}\sigma + B^{\alpha}$. But why does $\xi^{\alpha}(\sigma)$ increases linearly with $\sigma$ in **flat spacetime**? Shouldn't these geodesics be parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every straight line is a geodesic in flat space.  So, if two flat lines have nonzero geodesic deviation, this means that they come to some closest distance (which can be an intersection, but they don't have to be in a common plane), and then, in an infinitesimal approximation, the distance between them linearly increases.

But not all pairs of straight lines are mutually parallel.